# Stop pause and seek audio stream

Tags: node.js, audio

1) I'm using node-speaker and pause-stream like this:

```
        var mp3Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/sounds/' + filename);
        mp3Stream.pipe(new Lame.Decoder()).pipe(speaker);

        // ...
        function pause () { 
          if (isPlaying) {

              mp3Stream.pipe(pauseStream.pause());
              isPlaying = false;
          }
        }
```

and get audio stream paused only after a few seconds after pause() fired. How to use audio streams properly to prevent such bufferisation?

2) I switch tracks like this:

```
function play(params) { 

        if (isPlaying) {

            speaker.end();
            speaker = new Speaker({
                channels: 2,          // 2 channels
                bitDepth: 16,         // 16-bit samples
                sampleRate: 44100     // 44,100 Hz sample rate
            });
        }

        mp3Stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/sounds/' + params.filename);
        mp3Stream.pipe(new Lame.Decoder()).pipe(speaker);

        isPlaying = true;
}
```

Is it ok? I'm afraid I will get memory leaks

3) Is there easy way to seek audio buffers?

Thank you!